# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'

Tags: php, mysql

У меня не получается отобразить базу данных созданную в *phpmyadmin*. Данный код работал с другой БД. Немного изменил код под свою базу данных и в браузере выкидывает ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\DatabasesHomework\index.php on line 26

То есть в echo:

```
$row['car_name','car_fuel','car_engineSize','car_color'].' '.$row['car_ID'];
```

Что не так?

Файл index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php

        include 'connect.php';
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT car_name,car_fuel,car_engineSize,car_color FROM motor_vehicles ORDER BY car_ID DESC');
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
    {
            echo '<ol>';
        while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {

                    echo '<li>';
                    echo $row['car_name','car_fuel','car_engineSize','car_color'].' '.$row['car_ID'];

                    echo '</li>';
                }
                echo '</ol>';
        }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Файл connect.php

```
    <?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
$DB_HOST = 'localhost';
$DB_USER = 'root';
$DB_PASS = '';
$DB_NAME = 'motor_vehicles';

try {
    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_HOST};dbname={$DB_NAME}", $DB_USER, $DB_PASS);
    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: очевидно `echo $row['car_name','car_fuel','car_engineSize','car_color'].`....... что это по-вашему?

Comment: Это не считая того, что `car_ID`  у вас в выборке вообще отсутствует.

Comment: что нужно изменить?

Comment: Разобрался =), спасибо .

Answer (score 2):

Вместо:

```
$row['car_name','car_fuel','car_engineSize','car_color']
```

Должно быть:

```
$row['car_name'].$row['car_fuel'].$row['car_engineSize'].$row['car_color']
```